# Get select information before submitting

Tags: ajax, select, live

well i was reading around the solutions that stack-overflow was giving but i couldn't find the correct one... so here is my question:

Im creating a form with multiple selects ( not the select multiple="true" ) , no , i mean a form with lets say 4 different selects... retrieving data from a database so if i fill my first "select" lets say Style1 then i would like to get the "style1" selection so i can configure my second select query based on that and i can DISTINCT the values im looking for... i don't know if you get my idea, i've read i need to use AJAX but i couldn't figure out how to...

---

```
<form method="post">
<select name="category">
<?php $test = mysql_query("SELECT category FROM test_table GROUP BY category");
while($testing = mysql_fetch_array($test)){
echo "<option value=".$testing["category"].">".$testing["category"]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<select name="model">
<?php $test2 = mysql_query("SELECT model FROM test_table WHERE model = 'TRYING TO COMPARE WITH THE VALUE WITH THE FIRST SELECT' GROUP BY model");
while($testing2 = mysql_fetch_array($test2)){
echo "<option value=".$testing2["model"].">".$testing2["model"]."</option>";
</select>
</form>
```

Well that was just to get an idea, is not like the real one but its a pretty close example.

1. Sorry for my weird spelling
2. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="category" onchange="javascript:getDroupDownValues(this.value);">
    <?php $test = mysql_query("SELECT category FROM test_table GROUP BY category");?>
    <?php while($testing = mysql_fetch_array($test)):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $testing["category"];?>"><?php echo $testing["category"];?></option>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    </select>
    <div id="model-category">

    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDroupDownValues(value)
{

    jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        evalScripts: true,
        url: 'your ajax url', // example your site url /ajax.php
        data: ({category:value}),
        success: function(data, textStatus) {            
            jQuery("#model-category").html(data);
        }
    });    
}
</script>
```

Now in ajax.php script

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['category']) && $_REQUEST['category']):?>
    <select name="model">
    <?php $test2 = mysql_query("SELECT model FROM test_table WHERE model = '{$_REQUEST['category']}' GROUP BY model");?>
    <?php while($testing2 = mysql_fetch_array($test2)):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $testing2["model"];?>"><?php echo $testing2["model"];?></option>
    <?php endwhile;?> 
  </select>    
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thank you very very very very very much! =) the last question of this weird thing! =) if i would like to add new select's to this, i will have to create different php ajax files? :o? sorry for my ignorace and thanks for helping me i owe you way too much... =) <3

Comment: @CarlosOyaneder you can create new script or you can implement logic in same ajax file based on condition.you can accept and up vote if this Answer is usefull

Comment: well come  @CarlosOyaneder